# What do you call it when someone searches through your stuff?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, expressions, phrases

This is one of the things that I don't really know the proper name for, because I've never heard anyone say it, but I know how to explain it.

Let's say a toddler is searching through your backpack, then you tell him:

> Stop -blank- my things!

Can you guys provide more than one expression?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This question seems to be asking about two actions. One is someone 'going through' a backpack. The other one is 'going through the things found in a backpack'.

> Stop going through my things

fits the second case.

As does the expression you provided:

> Stop searching through my stuff

User3169 has provided a highly idiomatic expression:

> Stop digging through my things

CopperKettle has provided the useful verb *rummage* (which is also a noun):

> Stop rummaging (through) my backpack

Also, *stop messing with my things/stuff* is similar, but it is broader in meaning.

You can also say

> Get your hands out of my backpack
>
> Leave my stuff alone
>
> Find your own toys to play with

For variety and vocabulary expansion, you might want to be aware of

> Stop rifling through my things

but *[rifle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rifle#rifle-2)* as a verb means to *go through something quickly in order to steal something*, and we wouldn't generally use that for a toddler.

Note: I have not used a period after any of the italicized examples, because I want to leave open the fact that you can add *, toddler's name* or something else  the end of each one.

> Stop messing with my stuff, lovey dovey.

Answer (score 6):

> Stop **digging through** my things!

For a person (older than a toddler anyway), also:

> Stop **snooping in** my things!

Comment: Can you use *stuff* instead of *things*?

Comment: I don't understand the age concern.

Comment: @tchrist It is because *snooping* indicates intentional searching for something. I doubt a toddler would do this, rather it is just due to curiosity.

Comment: @Ale you can use *stuff*, but since it is a mass noun, it would refer to all the things as one unit. It removes the notion of going from one item to another.

Comment: +1 for both, powerful and to the point, better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

rifling - the act or process of ransacking (or robbing). Definition #2 at dictionary.com.

Comment: -1 because the word is already in the community answer

Answer (score 1):

Stop **snooping around**. I've heard it used mainly in the context of infidelity, e. g. going through someone's messages. But it sounds appropriate here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

> Stop **rooting around** my personal belongings!

*root around* is a phrasal verb that is defined by [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/root-around-somewhere) as:

> to ​search for something, ​especially by ​looking through other things

And gives the following example as to its usage:

> She was ​rooting around in her ​drawer for a ​pencil.

But I have heard it used in the context that you mention (and a [quick Google search for "stop rooting around my"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22stop%20rooting%20around%20my%22) would point to many examples in that same vein).

Answer (score -3):

If the person is of questionable character, the verb "lurp" would be acceptable. "Hey dirtbag, there will be no lurping through my backpack while I'm in the other room".

Comment: I've never heard that used before (AmE) - do you have a reference that isn't Urban Dictionary? Slang is fun, but you should probably explain that it's pretty casual.